# Context menu within a menu item in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I have a Menu that contains a TreePanel. The users need to be able to interact with a the TreePanel's nodes using a context menu. I'm showing the context menu from a function attached to the TreePanel's `contextmenu` event.

This works except:

1. Without `allowOtherMenus: true`, showing the context menu causes the main menu, and therefore the TreePanel, to disappear ;
2. With `allowOtherMenus: true` on either menu, the context menu doesn't disappear when the users clicks a blank area of the TreePanel.

I'm looking for a way to have the context menu to work as if the TreePanel were not an item within a menu.

**Mockup :**
[image]

Comment: not sure I follow you, can you post a working example on http://jsfiddle.net and then I can take a look?

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't support ExtJS beyond Ext Core, so I can't make a Menu or TreePanel there. I added a picture instead.

Comment: ok, so when the user clicks anywhere in treepanel (not on a node) you want the menu to disappear?

Comment: That's right, in that case I want the context menu to disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this that seems to work on FF3/IE8/Chrome, although it could have side effects that have not shown up yet.

```
var hide_context_menu = function () { context_menu.hide() };

var context_menu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
    allowOtherMenus: true,
    items: [...],
    listeners: {
        show: function () {
            Ext.getDoc().on('mouseup', hide_context_menu);
        },
        hide: function () {
            Ext.getDoc().un('mouseup', hide_context_menu);
        }
    }
});
```

`allowOtherMenus: true` prevents the hiding of the main menu by the MenuMgr when the context menu pops up. Hiding the handler to the mouseup event allows for click events to be processed.

Comment: That should work yeah, I had something like that in bind but binding to the `click` event, that will work better though. Just monitor it and see if there are any strange issues